# Recovered RAID10 after 2 disks failed but VMs unable to boot

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines

Last week I had 2 ssd's fail on my RAID10 array of 4 ssd's. I managed to rebuild the RAID, however then a 3rd ssd failed so had to rebuild that - the end result was that it rebuilt all OK.

It is worth noting this server runs ESXi with around 10 hosts running ubuntu 14.04 ( I know its on my list to patch). ESXi boots up and I can log into it and see no errors - perfect, however it's a different story with my vm's.

Issue begins when I boot up any VM running ubuntu, I get presented with the rescue grub stating the normal.mod file is missing. I check all the partitions but I am unable to find any .mod files. I then find a solution to recover the .mod files if they are not there by using the kernel files (https://gutsytechster.wordpress.com/2018/07/24/how-to-resolve-grub-error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found/). Unfortunately this didn't work.

When I try and present a live CD and try to recover the boot drive I go through these steps:

- Select device to use as root system
- Try and execute a shell in said root system

[Result of trying to execute shell on partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALKb0.png)

My question is, after all of this, is there any hope left or is it a case of rebuilding everything?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: hm, i would try to boot bia live System, mount the drive and chroot /dir and see what happens, usually it eill tell you a bit more as the grafical interfaces

Comment: do you know of any resource that I could read on that ? i am looking at the help ubuntu recover grub page but unable to perform any of the commands via the live shell. Thanks for your help :)